# Does it make sense to do a select() when using ONLY 1 non-blocking socket?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, nonblocking

My application has ONLY 1 Unix TCP socket that it uses to recv() and send(). The socket is non-blocking. Given this, is there an advantage in doing a select() before a send()/recv()?

If the underlying TCP pipe is not ready for an I/O, the send()/recv() should immediately return with an EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN. So, what's the point of doing a select()? Seems like, it might only cause an additional system call overhead in this case. Am I missing anything?

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention: The application is single-threaded.

Comment: Depends on what the rest of your program does. You have to wait somewhere, if there is nothing to do. Select is a good place to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your socket is *non-blocking*, then you need `select` (or preferably `poll`, which does not have the broken `FD_SETSIZE` limit and associated dangers) to block for you in place of the blocking that would be taking place (if the socket were not non-blocking) in `send` and `recv`. Otherwise you will spin, using 100% cpu time to do-nothing. In most cases, you could just as easily make the socket blocking and do away with `select`/`poll`. However, there is one interesting case to consider: blocking IO *could* deadlock if your program is blocked in `send` and the program at the other end of the socket is also blocked in `send` (or the opposite). With non-blocking IO and `select`/`poll`, you naturally detect this situation and process the pending input when writing your output is not possible.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. "... if your socket is _non-blocking_... in place of the blocking that would be taking place in send and recv." -- but why would a non-blocking socket block in send or recv in the first place? Aren't they supposed to return immediately if there is nothing in the pipe? I understand the concern about spinning which could be avoided if the application sleeps when send/recv doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: I've edited to clarify: "...that would be taking place (if the socket were not non-blocking) in send and recv."

Comment: Sleeping is absolutely the wrong answer because you don't know *how long* you need to sleep. If you sleep too long, you'll delay responsiveness. If you don't sleep long enough, you'll cause excessive cpu load and waste lots of electricity (and thus money, or your client's/employer's/etc.'s money). Blocking is the act of sleeping for exactly the right amount of time: until the event you're waiting for occurs.

Comment: My initial edit (and comment) had a mistake, so I've fixed them now.

Comment: Thanks. I think your modified response makes sense. So, the bottom line seems to be that it almost always make sense to use a select()/poll() before doing a send()/recv() (irrespective of whether the socket is blocking or non-blocking).

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing. If, like you said, you only have a single socket, and no other events that you might need to respond to while waiting for IO on the socket, then you can just put it in blocking mode and use `send`/`recv` without `select`/`poll`. This approach also works fine if your application is multithreaded and you have a dedicated thread interfacing with the socket. But in other situations, you need `select`/`poll`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do recv() in a loop, but then you'll be consuming a lot of CPU time.

Better to wait on select() to avoid the extra CPU overhead. If you need to be doing background tasks, add a timeout to select() so you can wake periodically, even with no network traffic.

Comment: Just to give a quick background, our application currently uses blocking sockets with select(). I am trying to move to non-blocking sockets. Even when using blocking sockets, if select() tells us there is nothing in the pipe, we don't do the send() or recv(), instead we go back and see if any other interesting events happened (like user requested the application to shutdown and if so carry out that request). I can do the same with non-blocking sockets -- if send() or recv() would block, I can go back and see if any interesting events happened and if so act on them.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is letency sensitive then in may be justified to spin in a tight recv() loop without select() and give it a dedicated CPU (otherwise scheduler will punish it and you end up having massive latency). If your app cannot afford it but still does gie a thread to serve this socket then just make the socket blocking on read side and let scheduler wake your thread up when data is available. On the sending side again depends on what you need, either make the socket blocking or spin.

Only if your application is single threaded and the logic is "receive-process-reply" you absolutely need a non blocking read/write socket, selector, and a write queue, so that you receive when data is there, process, pit response to the queue, register for writability, flush the queue to the socket when writable, unregister from writability. readability is to be registered for all the time.

Comment: Spinning in a non-blocking `recv` loop will give *worse* latency than using `select` properly. The possible solutions are using a blocking socket or using `select`. Spinning and sleeping are both **bugs**.

Comment: No, just intuition. :) Spamming `recv` will repeatedly acquire and release the lock (in kernelspace) for the socket, causing contention or at least memory synchronization delays with the kernel's access to the socket buffer to deliver the message when it does arrive. Since a thread spinning on `recv` is going to be spending *most* of its time in or transitioning to/from kernelspace, you have a high likelihood that the packet you're waiting for will arrive *while* you're in `recv`, in which case you won't get it until the *next* iteration...

Comment: ...and since syscalls are expensive, and you're likely to end up making an extra syscall because of the above issue, you're going to increase your latency.

Comment: syscall is 3us on a 2.9 GHz 2.6+ kernel. there cannot be contention on the socket buffer as there is only one reader. there is no such thing as BKL anymore. And kernel space mutexes are spinlocks. So you get close to those 3us as your latency number. Once you park in select (epoll rather, if we are in low latency zone), you will sleep for quite a while if the socket is not readable at the time of parking and you are guaranteed to have a full context switch. I would appreciate if you stopped down voting questions on this site driven by just your intuition.

Comment: 3us is a lot: 9000 cycles. Anyway downvote was not based on intuition but on suggesting a harmful design that would amount to premature optimization even if it were an improvement on a non-optimization, beginner question.

Comment: One should distinguish between "early phase justified design decisions" and "premature optimization". I have explained in which case which design to prefer from desired latency profile and coding work involved. I thought I have covered most implementation flavors in unbiased way: tight spinning, blocking socket + thread per socket, non blocking single threaded IO loop.

Comment: Since your "early phase justified design decision" has no precedent or evidence that it's beneficial, and **lots** of reasons it's harmful, the burden of proof is on you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30583/discussion-between-bobah-and-r)